# git.Run() had no output

Tags: git, msysgit, tortoisegit

I created git repository previously and then I started working on a project which was on the server. I did push and pull just fine. But later on due to some conflicts, I deleted my local repository.

But now whenever I try to create a local repository, I get the following error:

`git.Run() had no output`.

I didn't found any solution on net after searching a lot.

Don't know what happened with TortoiseGIT and msysgit.

Comment: Which msysgit are you using? http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=667 mentions that recent msysgit releases fix this.

Comment: I am using `msysGit-fullinstall-1.8.1.2-preview20130201`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**1.**  Uninstall `TortoiseGit`

**2.**  Delete `TortoiseGit` registry using `regedit.exe` on windows.

**3.**  Reinstall `TortoiseGit`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The [issue 667](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=667) from TortoiseGit mentions:

> I had the problem too and fixed it:
>
> In the `TortoiseGit Settings --> General`, you have to specify the following folder for "`Git.exe Path`": "`C:\msysgit\bin`" and not "`C:\msysgit\git`" ("`C:\msysgit`" your individual msysGit-Root)
> After clicking on "`Check now`" the "`.dll`" should be passed automatically and the versionnumer should be displayed which is not the case if you use the git folder.

[image: git exe]

Comment: I already went through this link and tried this but this is not helping me out as I checked these settings and they are all fine. Also as I mentioned in the question that the repository was created before but not now.

Comment: @SaurabhJain which version of TortoiseGit are you using?

Comment: `TortoiseGit-1.8.1.0-32bit`

Comment: @SaurabhJain and you try to create a brand new repo, using a path with a root directory which doesn't exist yet? In your case, why not try and *clone* your remote repo?

Comment: I am trying to create the repo at the same folder path as it was previously and I don't want to clone remote repo. I just want to create a local git repo.

Comment: @SaurabhJain but does the directory in which you want to create the repo already exist or not?

Comment: I am using windows and after going into that folder, I am right clicking and I can see an option "Git Create repository here..." and when I click on this option, I get the popup which says "Make it Bare" and when I click ok, it gives me another popup which says "git.Run() had no output".

Comment: @SaurabhJain bare? Why would you make it bare? It would not have any working tree for you to checkout files. It would only have a git repo structure. Can you try and *not* "make it bare"?

Comment: the popup has the check mark to make it bare but I am not marking it checked and then pressing ok.

Comment: @SaurabhJain ok, can you try and create a repo *elsewhere* just to see if the problem persists?

Comment: :( sorry the same problem everywhere.

Comment: @SaurabhJain and what path are you using? If you want to create a repo on `C:\a\b\c`, `a\b` must exist, `c` must not exist yet (and will be created by the repo creation).

Comment: The paths are all fine because in windows you can go directly on folders(without using cmd) and then create repo there by just right clicking.

Comment: @SaurabhJain provided the final directory does not exist: git will create it. Speaking of which, could you create it through git command line? `cd C:\a\b`, then `git init c`? Just to see if it works, and if TortoiseGit can recognize it?

Comment: ok, creating git using command as you mentioned worked fine and now I can see .git folder created. But this is only happening by using your command and not directly by right click. Meanwhile I reinstalled `msysgit` and tried to create repo again. Now the error changes to "Git has not installed".

Comment: @SaurabhJain that means TortoiseGit doesn't correctly detect git, then.

Comment: but if that's the case then why I am able to create repo by using terminal and doing `git init c`.

Comment: @SaurabhJain because you are using a [`git-cmd` session](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat) or a `git-bash` session, coming directly from your msysgit distro, which sets `HOME` and `PATH` correctly.